# Triangles in a C++ STL Vector as an Objective-C member sometimes draws incorrectly in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

The polygons draw correctly 80% of the time. When it fails, a vertex is dislocated. The polygon is consistently drawn with the wrong vertex. I checked that the vector is correct during initialization, even when it's wrongly drawn.

I'm using Cocos2d.

The class member:

```
@interface Polygon : CCSprite {
  std::vector<float> triangleVertices;
}
```

The draw function called in [Polygon draw]:

```
+ (void)drawTrianglesWithVertices:(const std::vector<float> &)v
{   
    //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &v[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, v.size());

    //glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your vector is a vector of floats, where each consecutive pair of floats represents a single vertex, as suggested by your `glVertexPointer` call, then it should surely be `v.size()/2` in `glDrawArrays`, but I'm not that sure this would cause your error, otherwise some more information and code would be required.